# How to run a substitution matching a word between a space and a special character in Vim?

Tags: objective-c, regex, vim

I have the follow code:

```
@synthesize property1;
@synthesize property2;
@synthesize property3;
@synthesize property4;
```

I want them to end like

```
@synthesize property1 = _property1;
@synthesize property2 = _property2;
@synthesize property3 = _property3;
@synthesize property4 = _property4;
```

I'm using Vim and have been trying to come up with a solution that will math the property name between the space and `;`, but everything I've tried gives me a match including the two delimiters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
:%s#^\(@synthesize\s\)\(.*\);#\1\2 = _\2;#
```

Answer (score 2):

That’s the most minimal one that will work I guess:

```
:1,4s/\([a-z0-9]\+\);/\1 = _\1;/g
```

Note that `1,4` is the range of lines on which to apply this search and replace command.

More details can be found on http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Answer (score 2):

A concise substitution command can be used to solve the issue:

```
:%s/@synthesize \zs\w\+/& = _&/
```

Answer (score 0):

```vim
:perldo s/\@\w+\s\K(.*?);/ = _$1;/g
```